# Django not redirecting to the web page

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am creating a messaging application in django with a built-in DLP system. I want to redirect to a web page when a sensitive word is detected in the message. But the webpage is not being redirected to. It is showing in the terminal but not on the front-end.

In consumers.py

```
async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']

        if (re.findall("yes|Yes", message)):
            response = await requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/dlp/')
            print('message')
            
        else:
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username
        }))
```

The output in the terminal

```
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/2/ [127.0.0.1:32840]
HTTP GET /dlp/ 200 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:32842]
message
```

Answer (score 0):

Now your backends requests `/dlp` page, receives the response and prints string `'message'` to console. It doesn't send any data to frontend.

The most simple solution, I think, will be to add `status` field to your json and handle it in javascript.

```
async def chat_message(self, event):
    message = event['message']
    username = event['username']

    if re.findall("yes|Yes", message):
        print('message')
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'status': 1,
            'redirect_to': '/dlp/',
        }))
    else:
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'status': 0,
            'message': message,
            'username': username,
        }))
```

```js
const socket = new WebSocket(...) // url of WS here
socket.onmessage = ev => {
    data = json.loads(ev.data);
    if (data.status === 1){
        window.location.href = new URL(data.redirect_to, window.location.origin);
    } else if (!data.status) {
        // handle normal message
    } else {
        alert('Error code forgotten!')
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work. If i input this code, even the message does not send.

Comment: Of course, nobody's going to write whole application for you. The part I provided does exactly one thing: when you submit message with `yes` string, it responds with failure code 1, that can be handled in JS. This JS snippet doesn't bother sending message and sending a rocket to the space - should it? You probably have a program for that anyway, and it's far beyond the question. Your logic to send message should remain unchanged.